# Survival function for Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Could you please help me to find a survival function for Poisson distribution? I'm very new to this topic. Poisson distribution probability mass function:

$$f(k) = P(X = k) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}.$$

So, I found a general definition of survival function:

$$S(t) = P(T > t) = \int_t^\infty f(u)\,du = 1 - F(t).$$

But as I understand, this one suits only continuous distributions and Poisson is a discrete one. Then I found this definition, which seems to suit a discrete case:

$$S(t_j) = S_j = P(T \geq t_j) = \sum_{k=j}^\infty f(k).$$

But as I wasn't counting it earlier, I'm not sure how to apply it. I need it for my university project. Also, found that this is a survivor function for Poisson:
[image]
But don't know how to find it.

Comment: Do you want the answer - or would you prefer an hint that would help you derive the answer. The first is easier - but the latter is more fun ... your choice.

Comment: Different people define the survival function differently for discrete distributions, either as $\mathbb P(T \gt t)=1-F(t)$ or as $\mathbb P(T \ge t)$

Comment: @firdaus as it's quite urgent for me now, I would like to see a solution if you have it.

Comment: @Henry thanks for this note. Then I more interested in this definition:  $\mathbb P(T \gt t)=1-F(t)$ .

Comment: @StubbornAtom it seems like something similar, but I don't see anything that it is a survival function, also other markings and task is really different. Maybe, because I'm new to this it doesn't fully answer my question.